# Socket Programming cannot connect to server (host unreacheable)

Tags: android, sockets

I have an app running on the my Google Nexus tablet running on `4.3 JellyBean`, which connects to the `server(IP 50.30.233.162)`. The app is unable to connect to the server and gives the error message as "host not reachable".

I checked the -> `InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString();` from the app and it gives "`localhost/127.0.0.1`" But the actual IP of the device is "`50.20.32.225`"

I have also given the permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE/>
```

I am really stuck, any help would be great.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
Socket socket = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        String serverAddress = "50.30.233.162";
        new Connecting().execute(serverAddress);
}


private class Connecting extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>{


    protected String doInBackground(String... serverAdd) {

        String serverAddress = serverAdd[0];

        try {

            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
            editText.setText(InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString());

            int serverPort = 5789;
            socket = new Socket(serverAddress, serverPort);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }



        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

This is my server code

public class Server {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    //  TupleSpaceServer tupleServer = new TupleSpaceServer();

        ServerSocket server = null;
        Socket client = null;
        String serverIpAdd = null;

        int portAdd;
        serverIpAdd = InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString();
        String[] serverAdd = serverIpAdd.split("/");
        serverIpAdd = serverAdd[1];
        portAdd = 5789;
        System.out.println("Server is now online");
        System.out.println("Server IP Address: " + serverIpAdd);
        System.out.println("Port Address: " + portAdd);
        server = new ServerSocket(portAdd);

        while (true) {
            client = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Client Connected Address: "
                    + client.getInetAddress());
        //  new Thread(new SessionThread(client, tupleServer)).start();
            server.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }

}
```

}

Server is now online
Server IP Address: 50.30.233.162
Port Address: 5789

Comment: The local address of the device running the application has nothing to do with the server address. I don't understand this part of your question. The message you are getting indicates that the address mentioned isn't reachable from the client. Your client code is pretty confusing, with the server address hardwired twice for some reason. I suggest you clean it up.

Comment: You use another IP Address in the code as described in the question text.

Comment: I cleaned up the code. My question is, the client is unable to make a connection to the server and I do not know the reason. I am assuming the client is connecting via the address 127.0.0.1 which it should not. It should connect through the internet address.

Comment: *Why* do you assume the client is connecting to 127.0.0.1 when your have hardcoded otherwise? You don't seem to understand your own code.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing obviously wrong here, it's probably a networking issue.

I would start by using tcpdump or wireshark on the server side to see if connections really make it in.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured the problem. It is the router problem. My router is blocking communication between devices. I could not figure out the changes in the router that had to be made but I switched to another router and everything works fine now.

For the time being I am going to stick to the second router and not go into details making changes to the old one.